# Cannot change Projects location in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallels

On a fresh install of Visual Studio 10, my Projects location defaults to "Visual Studio 2010Projects", User project templates location is "Visual Studio 2010Templates\ProjectTemplates", and User item templates location is "Visual Studio 2010Templates\ItemTemplates".

The result of this is that when I open my solution, these folders are created relative to my solution, rather than using the generic settings of my VS installation.

When I change these settings to be specific to VS rather than relative to my solution, it all looks fine until I close and reopen VS, whereby the bad defaults are reset. I can't get it to remember my changes, and have tried exporting settings etc to no avail.

I suspect that this problem is related to running Windows 7 on a Mac using Parallels, because I have never had this happen before.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update: After a few other things went a bit skew-whiff with my setup (inc NuGet failing to update etc), I actually started from scratch using a Boot Camp partition. This current installation is far more stable, and I can still wrap Parallels around the Boot Camp partition - I guess Parallels is just not quite 100% perfect for installing Windows.

Comment: Did you reinstall the entire OS or just Visual Studio? I'm having the exact same problem, but I'm running on a "normal" PC with Windows 7.

Comment: In my case, I reinstalled the entire OS. I've never had this problem happen with a "normal" setup - but TBH, I can't really remember any further details I'm afraid! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Late post, but I thought I'd give my 2 cents for future visitors. I've run VS2008 through VS2012 without any problems in Parallels, personally, for several years now.  It's not that Parallels can't handle it per-say, but you need to configure it properly.

An important thing to remember as a developer using Parallels is that you should shut off all the fancy file integration features, i.e. shared Desktop, shared Documents folder, that sort of thing.  Not only do you clutter up your Mac folders with Windows junk, but essentially your Documents folder gets remapped as a network share like \.PSF\Home\Documents.  And we all know how Windows has problems with installing programs into and across network shares.